# Is there a way to show Single Variation prices in the product loop when filters or attributes are active?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, variables

I have a WooCommerce store with variable products. Some products have 3 different attributes that are used for variations ie; Size, Comfort Level and Turning Cycle (as an example). I would like to know if there is a way to display these products seperately in the product loop when a filter is active.

So let's say that I have a filter (by attribute) for size, then in my filters I will have small, medium and large. But when I use these filters WooCommerce still displays the variable product with it's start and end price in a range ie $100-$200.

Is there a way to only show the price of the variable that you have filtered out? If you choose large, then the price changes to $200 instead of staying $100-$200.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I would also like to know how this could be possible